# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown while reading data from text file

Tags: c#

I m trying to read a text file data with "|" separated, I m using below code. I m able to read the data from text file after reading when trying to put datatable data into dataview I m getting Exception of type **'System.OutOfMemoryException'** was thrown,

Can any one suggest me how to avoid this exception.

```
string filepath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["data"];  

if (filepath != "")
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("file");
                string[] columns1 = null;
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
                int Count = lines.Length;
                //here taking columns and adding to table
                 if (lines.Count() > 0)
                {
                    columns1 = lines[0].Split(new char[] { '|' });
                    foreach (var column in columns1)
                        dt.Columns.Add(column);
                }                   
                 for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count(); i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    string[] values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { '|'  });
                    for (int j = 0; j < values.Count() && j < columns1.Count(); j++)
                    {
                      dr[j] = values[j];
                    }

                }
                 dt.Rows.Add(dr);   

                    DataView View = new DataView(dt);
                    //Here I m getting "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."
                    DataTable MD = View.ToTable("MD", false, "ID", "Description")
                    DataTable MM = View.ToTable("MM", false, "RecordNumber", "Item description")
                if (MD.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    InsertData(MD);
                }
                if (MM.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    InsertData1(MM);
                }
            }
```

**StackTrace :-**

```
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
    at System.Data.DataView.ToTable(String tableName, Boolean distinct, String[] columnNames)
```

Comment: what is the size of a file?

Comment: Line of the exception (full trace). The issue is most likely file size, or number of entries in your file exceeding the maximum number of items allowed in a list.

Comment: I m trying to read text file which is having 5lacks of records.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should really use the `Length` property of an array, instead of the `Count()` extension method.

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Comment: I Have more upto 50 columns are there

Answer (score 0):

Multiple uses of String.Split are likely to cause an OutOfMemoryException.  Download Lumenworks Fast CSV Reader - problem solved.  You will get it here:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

For more details on issues with Split, have a look at the following links:

http://vpnchoudhary.blogspot.ie/2011/03/out-of-memory-exception-simple.html

[string.split() "Out of memory exception" when reading tab separated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404435/string-split-out-of-memory-exception-when-reading-tab-separated-file)

Relevant quote here:

> What happens when you do a split on a string containing 1355049 comma
>   separated strings of 16 characters each, having total character length
>   of 25745930 ?
>
> An Array of pointers to string object: Contiguous virtual address
>   space of 4 (address pointer)*1355049 = 5420196 (arrays size) + 16 (for
>   book keeping) = 5420212. Non-contiguous virtual address space for
>   1355049 strings, each of 54 bytes. It does not mean all those 1.3
>   million strings would be scattered all across the heap, but they will
>   not be allocated on LOH. GC will allocate them on bunches on Gen0
>   heap. Split.Function will create internal array of System.Int32[] of
>   size 25745930, consuming (102983736 bytes) ~98MB of LOH, which is very
>   expensive L.

Comment: "Multiple uses of String.Split are likely to cause an OutOfMemoryException." -- You really should cite your sources if you're going to make a claim like this.

Comment: I have provided an edit - please remove your downvote.