# Parsing csv files with specific column delimiter & string enclosure using the CsvHelper library

Tags: c#, csv

I am using this http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ awesome library in my .NET C# project for my CSV parsing requirements.

If I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
SupplierSku,MappedSageSku
EG1234,EGCD1234
EG4567,EG-XZ567
```

I usually create a DTO class like this:

```
public class SkuMapping
{
    public string SupplierSku { get; set; }
    public string MappedSageSku { get; set; }
}
```

and parse the csv file like this:

```
// Open & parse selected csv file
var csvReader = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(selectSkuMapping.Text));
var skuMappings = csvReader.GetRecords<SkuMapping>();

// Do something with each row
foreach (SkuMapping skuMapping in skuMappings)
{
    // ...
}
```

This works great for pre-defined / structured CSV files.

I now have the requirement to parse arbitrary CSV files, where they may contains various `column delimiter` & `string enclosure` and exact number of columns on csv is not known, but the column index containing the data I need is known.

#### Example #1

```
PartNumb,InStock,PrGroup
"A-X-1230",Y,103
"B-DD-1231",Y,103
```

Where;  `column delimiter` = `,` and `string enclosure` = `"`

Data I need: Column index `0` (PartNumb) and Column index `1` (InStock)

#### Example #2

```
SupplierSku,CatIds,StockStatus,Active
%ADA-BB-124%|4,5,1|%AV%|1
%XAS-E4-S11%|97,41,65|%OS%|0
```

Where;  `column delimiter` = `|` and `string enclosure` = `%`

Data I need: Column index `0` (SupplierSku) and Column index `2` (StockStatus)

---

So given the above, what is the best way to use the `CsvHelper` library to parse arbitrary csv files (where `column delimiter`, `string enclosure` and `column indexes` are known)? I also need the option to skip first row on csv (sometimes csv contains header row and sometimes they dont).

Comment: Why do you need to use the helper at all? Surely you could read it line by line, split by the delimiter and pick out the number indexed entries as needed?

Comment: Helper libraries exists to prevent you reinventing the wheel. I thought since I am already using this library extensively in my app, I'll use it again for parsing arbitrary csv files also. Does this mean `CsvHelper` won't be able to help with my requirement? Do I need to parse the files manually?

Comment: According to the documentation, you can use it as a reader instead.

Comment: I find lumenworks great when you have quick reading of a CSV to do.  Beware of using string operation ssuch as split() as they can lead to outOfMemoryExceptions.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327971/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-while-reading-data-fr/32328355#32328355

Comment: Csv is not so easy to parse with line split. Robust code needs a real implementation.

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO agreed, that's why I am using a tried & tested csv parser library instead of manually doing it (which is essentially reinventing the wheel).

Comment: you re totally right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work, using CsvHelper:

```
var textToParse = @"SupplierSku,CatIds,StockStatus,Active
%ADA-BB-124%|4,5,1|%AV%|1
%XAS-E4-S11%|97,41,65|%OS%|0";

string supplierSku;
string stockStatus;

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(textToParse))
{
    using (var reader = new CsvReader(stringReader))
    {
        reader.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
        reader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true; // If there is no header, set to false.

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            supplierSku = reader.GetField("SupplierSku"); // Or reader.GetField(0)
            stockStatus = reader.GetField("StockStatus"); // Or reader.GetField(2)

            Console.WriteLine($"SKU: {supplierSku}; Status: {stockStatus}");
        }
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't automatically trim/remove the quote characters - you can easily do that yourself using `Trim()` or `Substring()`. There is a little more manual effort involved, but it is still easier than doing it manually.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was after. Thanks.

Comment: When IO try this it says that the delimiter and header reader properties are read on;ly.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle see this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65962764/951577

Comment: @EuanT Thanks for the link. But I seem to have bigger problems. It turns out that none of my CvsHelper stuff is working anymore in my release builds of C++. All functions return saying that the file was not found. Debug is fine. I raised it on the CsvHelper repository.

Answer (score 5):

There was a package upgrade and the new syntax is now:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("./myfile.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, delimiter: ";", encoding: Encoding.UTF8)))
{
    //do something with csv
}
```

## Update

As pointed out in the comments and seemingly already migrated in my codebase new syntax is

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("./myfile.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ";", Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
{
    //do something with csv
}
```

Comment: When I try `using (var reader = new CsvReader(streamReader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, delimiter: ";", encoding: Encoding.UTF8)))` it says that `delimiter` is unknown.

Comment: This syntax does compile for me: `new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ",", Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what you want:

- Do you know which delimiter(s) are allowed before you start parsing?

If you don't know which delimiters are allowed, you are in trouble: Is 'A'a delimiter? Is 'B' a delimiter?. Let's assume there is a set of characters that you think are suitable as delimiters for the actual CSV stream you are going to parse.

1. Replace all occurrences of your delimiters with the same one, for example ';'
2. You can do this using String.Replace(char, char) for each accepted delimiter, or use a regular expression

   - Do you want to select your columns by number of by name?

If you only need certain columns, create a map where you tell the CsvHelper which column must be mapped to which destination.

Example: if you need to map column "MyColumn" to Property YourProperty create a map:

```
private sealed class MyCsvConverterMap : CsvClassMap<MyDestinationType>
{
    public MyCsvConverterMap()
    {
        Map(item => item.YourProperty).Name("MyColumn");
        // map all properties in your destination to a column
    }
}

using (TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(...))
{
    CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(txtReader);
    csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
    csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new MyCsvConverterMap());

    while (csvReader.Read())
    {
         MyDestinationType convertedRecord = csvReader.GetRecord<MyDestinationType>();
         ...
```

**Addition**

It is also possible to map by column number instead of mapping by column name. See an explanation of all kinds of maps:
[CsvHelper Getting started](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: This certainly looks interesting. As per my original question; for each csv file variation I am going to work with, I know the `column delimiter`, `string enclosure` and the index (not column name) that has the data I need. Given that, how can you use the fluent mapping to achieve the csv parsing?

Answer (score 1):

With a bit more effort you can also create a type-safe mapping with the `CsvClassMap` and inheriting from the `DefaultTypeConverter` class to create a converter for the CatIds (comma separated).

Here's an example that works for your example #2:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class CsvHelperTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var textToParse = "SupplierSku,CatIds,StockStatus,Active" + Environment.NewLine;
        textToParse += "%ADA-BB-124%|4,5,1|%AV%|1" + Environment.NewLine;
        textToParse += "%XAS-E4-S11%|97,41,65|%OS%|0";

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(textToParse))
        {
            using (var reader = new CsvReader(stringReader))
            {
                reader.Configuration.Quote = '%';
                reader.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
                reader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true; // If there is no header, set to false.
                reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<StockMap>();

                foreach(var stock in reader.GetRecords<Stock>())
                {
                    // normally do something with data, now just test

                    Assert.IsNotNull(stock.SupplierSku);
                    Assert.IsTrue(stock.SupplierSku.IndexOf('%') == -1, "Quotes should be stripped");
                    Assert.IsNotNull(stock.CatIds);
                    Assert.AreEqual(3, stock.CatIds.Length, "Expected 3 CatIds");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class StockMap : CsvClassMap<Stock>
    {
        public StockMap()
        {
            Map(stock => stock.SupplierSku).Index(0);
            Map(stock => stock.CatIds).Index(1).TypeConverter<CatIdsConverter>();
            Map(stock => stock.StockStatus).Index(2);
            Map(stock => stock.Active).Index(3); // 1 is true, 0 is false
        }
    }

    public class Stock
    {
        public string SupplierSku { get; set; }
        public int[] CatIds { get; set; }
        public StockStatus StockStatus { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
    }

    public enum StockStatus
    {
        AV, OS
    }

    public class CatIdsConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(string);
        }

        public override object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return null;

            var catIds = text.Split(',').Select(c=> Convert.ToInt32(c)).ToArray();
            return catIds;
        }
    }
}
```

For example #1 just configure Quote = '"', Delimiter = ",", Add another class & CsvClassMap<> implementation and configure that within another CsvReader.

Answer (score 0):

```
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(stream), true, ';')
```

Configuration.Delimiter it is not working any more, now you have to pass the delimiter as a param in the CsvReader initialization